# What vitamins are useful for restoring the skin after an injury?

Tags: dermatology, micronutrients, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

I was injured 4 weeks ago. After the removal of the stitches, either an atrophic or a normotrophic scar (about 1 cm long) was formed on my face. I would like to contribute to the skin and constitution for minimizing scarring and optimal healing. What vitamins will be useful for the skin in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you think vitamins help restore the skin? I can’t really see a connection (given that right now you eat the recommended daily amount of vitamins).

Answer (score -2):

Buy a bottle of vitamin E in liquid form, and massage the scar a *minimum* of twice daily for at least 3-6+ months. Everyone's skin will heal differently, but **consistency** provides for the best results your skin can obtain. Also, keeping your scar out of the sun as much as possible will help significantly. If you go outside wear a high SPF sunscreen to keep your scar from darkening.

Diet can accelerate any form of healing in general, especially high vitamin c foods. Vitamin C helps to heal skin blemishes, and is also a super antioxidant. Fruits and vegetables to look for are blueberries, broccoli, guava, kiwi, oranges, papaya, strawberries, and sweet potatoes. In many beauty stores or online you can find vitamin c oils/serums meant to put on your skin and promote healing.

Side note: if the scar is still visible after a year or so, a dermatologist may suggest laser treatment or other options.

Wishing you a speedy recovery!

Comment: Welcome! The following does not judge your answer on content but on form: Your answer would improve greatly if you backup your statements with robust evidence, references. You could cite studies and other relevant information regarding this (it‘s a Community Rule of the site). You are invited look at the other help documents. Especially [Quality of References](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/783/11231)